# Why is domainname dropped on not finding the FQDN

Tags: domain-name-system

I have seen this behaviour in Kali Linux and AIX 5.x:

Content of /etc/resolv.conf:

```
domain biman.net
nameserver 192.168.1.126
#nameserver 192.168.5.1
```

When a host is searched with shortname (e.g. "tttt"), first DNS query is tttt.biman.net. 'tttt' record is absent in DNS. The 2nd query is made without the domain name. Why? How can I stop it?

See the evidences -- Query:

```
nslookup -q=AAAA ttttt
Server:     192.168.1.126
Address:    192.168.1.126#53

** server can't find ttttt: SERVFAIL
```

Evidence ---tcpdump:

```
 14:42:56.073872 IP 192.168.1.119.58163 > 192.168.1.126.53: 58597+ 
 AAAA? ttttt.biman.net. (33)
 14:42:56.074407 IP 192.168.1.126.53 > 192.168.1.119.58163: 58597 
 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (105)
 14:42:56.074655 IP 192.168.1.119.34699 > 192.168.1.126.53: 32815+ 
 AAAA? ttttt. (23)
 14:42:56.074903 IP 192.168.1.126.53 > 192.168.1.119.34699: 32815 
 ServFail 0/0/0 (23)
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual behaviour of **libresolv** for single-label queries is:

1. Append the domains listed in the `search` directive (or the obsolete `domain` directive) to the label and performs a DNS query.
2. Perform a DNS query for a top-level domain.

However, at least on **glibc** version 2.14 or higher (cf. [resolv.conf manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html)), the second part can be suppressed with:

```
options no-tld-query
```

in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

**Edit**: This solution works if you resolve a hostname through **libc**, more precisely through the **libnss_dns** name service. Assuming you have:

```
hosts: files dns
```

in your [/etc/nsswitch.conf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html) file (most Linux desktop distributions have many other name services configured), you can check the `no-tld-query` options with:

```
getent hosts name_of_host
```

**nslookup** is a tool that bypasses the Name Services Switch and performs a DNS query independently. As your examples show, this solution does not work with nslookup, but will work with most of the other programs.

Comment: Thanks Piotr. My problem is not fixed yet. Two follow-up questions:1)  How do I verify the version of glibc? 2) Is there any kind of caching which remembers resolv.conf? I sometimes see different behaviour for same resolv.conf or the other way around.

Comment: Glibc version 2.14 was released in 2011, so you definitively have it. On Debianoids `apt policy libc6` or `dpkg-query --show libc6` gives you the version. The results of `getaddrinfo` might be cached by [nscd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/nscd.8.html), but it is rarely used. It is more probable that you have two nameservers, which give different results.

Comment: Can you post your new resolv.conf file after you edited it per Biman advice?

Comment: cat /etc/resolv.conf
  search biman.net
  nameserver 192.168.1.126
  nameserver 192.168.5.1
  options no-tld-query
tcpdump:
192.168.1.104.47957 > 192.168.1.126.53: 42121+ A? xxxx.biman.net. (32)
192.168.1.126.53 > 192.168.1.104.47957: 42121 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (104)
192.168.1.104.57785 > 192.168.1.126.53: 29150+ A? xxxx. (22)
192.168.1.126.53 > 192.168.1.104.57785: 29150 ServFail 0/0/0 (22)
nslookup query:
nslookup xxxx
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.1.126, trying next server
--snip--

--snip---

Comment: The `no_tld_query` setting is apparently ignored by **nslookup**, but works with **libnss_dns**, which is used by most programs. I added some details to the answer.